# How to fix duplication of item when deleted from RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am currently developing an app and I am using `RecyclerView` adapter, in the adapter I use listeners, to get buttons to work in every recyclers item. Now I have an option to delete the recycler item and everything is fine if the item is the last item in the `RecyclerView`. However, if it is at the beginning or the middle it gets replaced with the item which is next to it and the item duplicates.

Now this is the code for the activity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
mDbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
mDbAdapter.open();
listNotes = mDbAdapter.getResults();
mNotesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(this, mDbAdapter.fetchAllNotes(),listNotes);
mNotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listView_notes);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNotesAdapter);
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This is the adapter code:

The constructor:

```
public NotesAdapter(Context ctx, Cursor cursor, ArrayList<Note> listNotes){
    this.mCtx = ctx;
    this.mCursor = cursor;
    this.mListNotes = listNotes;
}
```

And the `onBindViewHolder`

```
//BIND DATA TO VIEWS
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return;
    }

    String noteT = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.COL_TITLE));
    String noteC = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT));
    holder.noteTitle.setText(noteT);
    holder.noteDescription.setText(noteC);
    holder.noteCard_settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(mCtx);
            mDbAdapter.open();
            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"The position is:"+holder.getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, view);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.popup_edit:
                            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You pressed edit note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.popup_delete:
                            deleteItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Delete note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}
```

And the other functions are like the following.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mListNotes.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private void deleteItem(int position) {
    mDbAdapter.deleteNoteById(mListNotes.get(position).getId());
    mListNotes.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, 1);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView noteTitle;
    TextView noteDescription;
    CardView cardView;
    Button noteCard_settingsButton;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        noteTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.note_titleView);
        noteDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.note_contentView);
        cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.notes_cardView);
        noteCard_settingsButton = view.findViewById(R.id.note_card_settings_button);
    }
}
```

So I expect the note to be fully removed and the notes after it, moved down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not updating the `mCursor` that you are using in your `onBindViewHolder` function. Though you are updating the `mListNotes`, you are still populating the data in each item of your `RecyclerView` from the cursor and the cursor is not being updated when you are deleting an item from the list.

I would rather recommend getting the data from your `ArrayList` (i.e. `mListNotes`) instead of the cursor in your `onBindViewHolder`. Modify the constructor like the following.

```
// Remove the mCursor completely.
// Looks like you do not need that. 
public NotesAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Note> listNotes){
    this.mCtx = ctx;
    this.mListNotes = listNotes;
}
```

And in your `onBindViewHolder` take the data from the `mListNotes`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String noteT = mListNotes.get(position).getTitle();
    String noteC = mListNotes.get(position).getContent();

    holder.noteTitle.setText(noteT);
    holder.noteDescription.setText(noteC);
    holder.noteCard_settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(mCtx);
            mDbAdapter.open();
            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"The position is:"+holder.getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, view);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.popup_edit:
                            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You pressed edit note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.popup_delete:
                            deleteItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Delete note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}
```

I hope that fixes your problem.

**In case you want to keep the cursor in your adapter, then make sure the cursor passed to the adapter is updated as well.**

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
private void deleteItem(int position) {
    mDbAdapter.deleteNoteById(mListNotes.get(position).getId());
    mListNotes.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mListNotes.size()); //change here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, 1);
```

You only need the call `notifyItemRemoved(position);`